# Saving user profile photos to S3

Tags: users, user-profile, s3

Is there a setting to get Craft to save user photos to S3 like a regular asset source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Craft 3 Update**

This is currently possible in Craft 3.  Install the [AWS S3](https://github.com/craftcms/aws-s3/) plugin from the Plugin Store. Make sure you're running Craft Pro.  Create a new Asset Volume using S3.  Go to Settings->Users->Settings in the Control Panel and set the "User Photo Location" setting to your S3 volume.

---

**Craft 2**

Currently no, although this is likely to change in the upcoming Craft 3.

Comment: Any way around this? Currently we are deployed on heroku, and its a read only file system. We cant store and save the user images on the site because of this restriction.

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of... sorry.

Comment: Silly follow up, but does Pixel and Tonic have any ideas for Craft 3 release date or what Craft 3 will be addressing?

Comment: Looks like this is still not possible?

Comment: @henry try this https://mijingo.com/blog/craft-3-remote-volumes-with-aws-s3

Comment: @henry updated answer.